# Chromium and Delphi XE5 + WebRTC not work

Tags: delphi, webrtc, chromium, delphi-xe5

I'm using Delphi and DCEF3 XE5 component but the problem is not loading correctly with WebRTC. Even putting the flags "--enable-media-stream" does not allow pick up the camera and microphone. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: what code you tried? what error you get?

Comment: Hello, then just put a TChromium the form, do the navigation for him through the test of WebRTC (https://apprtc.appspot.com/?r=90463706), and returns me a standard message stating that the site access the camera and microphone were denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, if someone has the same problem get solved them by doing one of the following points.

- Check if the webcam is being recognized by Google Chrome.
- Check that used the flag - enable-media-stream correctly in parameters.

These two steps solved my problem.